# What's an EL Expression?

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

So I'm playing with dynamic Visualforce components, tried adding an id like so:

```
Component.Apex.InputField f = new Component.Apex.InputField();
f.expressions.id = 'source';
```

And got this error message:

> Value assigned to expression field must be an EL expression

So I'm assuming at this juncture an EL expression is something like `{!someVar}`, but what does EL stand for? Have a nasty feeling I'm missing something blindingly obvious ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EL stands for Expression Language. As you guessed, it is the formula syntax used by Salesforce.

Comment: To elaborate, I am fairly certain the "EL" you are seeing is being thrown from Java, as in the EL used in JSP. More info here if you want a Java history lesson :) - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Expression_Language